# Question lock prevents commenting on any answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, android-app, locked-questions

There are several types of locks available for moderator use:

1. Content dispute
2. Historical significance
3. Offtopic comments

#2 - Historical - is special: when applied to a *question* it also locks all *answers*. But #1 and #3 only apply to the locked post itself: locking a question doesn't prevent the answers from being edited, voted on, or commented on.

The Android app doesn't appear to respect this distinction however, at least when it comes to comments:

[image: locked banner, no comment input]

Even though this answer isn't locked, the banner still shows - and no comment input is possible.

Comment: This is currently locked on the API side, questions have nothing but a `locked_date` to signify if they're locked or not. I don't know if this *should* be in the scope of the API's handling however, but it's definitely annoying.

Comment: This bit me again recently; the API *should* be returning per-post lock states (so answers wouldn't have a locked date on locked questions, except for the Historical Lock case). If that's not happening, I'd consider it an API bug.

Comment: we have a `can_flag` attribute in the API now, I'll look into adding a similar one for commenting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fixed as of the next build since we have a `can_comment` field on the API now, yay!